# 12.1.3. Oracle OAF. Get selected rows from Master-Detail tables

Tags: oaf

I have two advanced tables with Master-Detail relationship. These tables connected by ViewLink.  Also I have a Singe selector on Master level.

I need to get selected record from Master and Details tables.

[image]

I know how to get the Master row in particular method

```
XxOcmMatchHeaderVOImpl voHeader = getXxOcmMatchHeaderVO1();  
Row[] rowSelect = voHeader.getFilteredRows("SelectFlag", "Y");
```

But how can I get rows from Detail table?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ViewLink connects two VOs by some kind of id. Now you already have Master table's VO selected row. So you can now get an id from that row and filter Detail table's VO by that id.